# IP substring search when IP is stored as an integer

Tags: algorithm, search, ip

Let's say I have a lot of IPv4s stored as integers (specifically, in a relational database) and I want to do a substring search on them given a string representation of an IP.

For example, a user types in `12.3` and expects that they get back results such as `12.30.45.67`, `192.168.12.3`, `1.12.34.5`, `9.212.34.5`.

If the IP were a string, I could just do a plain substring search. It might not be efficient but it is at least simple to implement and understand. But because I can't readily change it into a string at the moment, I don't see any efficient (in terms of CPU cycles, memory, and also my development/implementation time) way of doing this, but maybe I am just missing something.

Comment: How are the IPs stored as integers? In 4 different fields of 8 bit integers for each part of them?

Comment: @user1984 single integer for all 4 octets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't missing anything.

For example try to turn `12.3` into a series of ranges.  In whichever octet the `12` is in, there will be 3 options (`12`, `112`, `212`).  In whichever octet the `3` is in there will be 2 options (`3` and `30-39`).  That's 6 range per combination of preceding octets.

But the preceding octets? We have `1 + 256 + 256*256` depending whether 0, 1 or 2 octets precede your start.

That's a grand total of `3 * 2 * (1 + 256 + 256*256) = 394758` ranges of numbers you have to search in.  It is unlikely that doing that many index searches will be faster than scanning everything.

Incidentally the worst case would be `1.2`.  In that case you'd have had `17 * 3 * (1 + 256 + 256*256) = 3355443` range lookups to do!

If they want this badly enough, you need to do a full text search on strings.

Comment: thanks for doing the calculations. i hadnt accurately counted the number of possibilities in the preceding octets, but even my much smaller number in my mind was already too big.

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than some pre-processing, indexing, caching in that case sounds too inefficient (and very hard to implement) to me.

Here are a few ideas:

1. Look into creating a custom index, if possible, that enables you do string search.
2. Add an automatic field to the table that represents the ip as a string and enable you to string search. Add a corresponding index of course.
3. If you can't or don't want to change the schema of that table, create another one with string representations of the rows in your ip table and corresponding foreign keys that map to the primary keys of the ip table.
4. If you don't want or can't edit that database at all, create an external key/value store/database where the keys are string representations of the ips and values hold the corresponding records of the ip table in the (now) external database or point to it.

In any case, I don't think searching in that table with its current form (integer) is feasible (both performance-wise and implementation complexity-wise) considering your requirements.